# Compare files between production-files and repository

Tags: git

I've gotten a bunch of productions-files sent over (a big-ass zip-file). I don't know, if there have been any modification in those files or not.

I have version-control on those files, using Bitbucket.

I'm looking for a way to tell git something along these lines:

> Yo Git! You know all those files in this directory here ( `/foo` )? Can I get you to, initially disregard all the files that you have in your `.gitignore`-file... And after that, compare `/foo` with `origin/master`, and create a merge-conflict if there are any differences.

I did this, and it worked. But it that really the correct approach? ... Are there a better/faster/cleaner way of doing it?

1. Unpack zip-file.
2. Enter it, and do `git init`.
3. Make a new branch: `git checkout -b myNewBranch`.
4. Add a .gitignore-file manually (from the `origin/master`-branch).
5. Commit it: `git commit -m 'Preping for changes'`.
6. Push it: `git push origin myNewBranch`.
7. Pull all branches (get my master-branch locally): `git pull -a`
8. Change to master-branch: `git checkout master`
9. Merge the two, and allow unrelated histories: `git merge myNewBranch --allow-unrelated-histories`.
10. Resolve the potential merge-conflict.
11. Commit and push it all: `git commit -m 'Production and master merge' && git push`

---

### Addition1

Based on what I wrote, then Jonas' comment would work (quite nicely, I assume). However, - I'm using a local development tool, that sets up a virtual environment, and a base-file structure - and then I can import the zip-file, so it's rolls it out on top of the base-file structure. And then I want to compare *that* with my Bitbucket-branch. I could try to move all the files out of the local development tool (so it's just a blank folder), - and then clone the repository to the local development root, - and then copy the production-files back and overwrite all the files and see which files has changes. But I'm afraid of messing too much with the local development tool, afraid that it'll break.

Comment: Your approach is a bit more involved than what I would've proposed: just unpack the zip inside the local repos, overwriting all the files. Then, `git diff` will tell you which files in the working tree have changes compared to `master` and you can still commit them. Also, no manual copying of `.gitignore`. Haven't tried it but that should do the trick, no?

Comment: I added some additional information to the question. Your suggestion would have worked under normal circumstance, I think.

Comment: Even with your addition1, I think @Jonas is right: setup everything using a `git clone` and whatever else your development tool sets up, then overwrite the local files with the contents of the zip and `git diff` etc will work. If you're worried about messing things up, do it all in a fresh sandbox that you're willing to throw away. As long as you don't commit and push anything, there will be no impact outside the sandbox.